# How can I generate a sequence of numbers in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Running through some Elixir exercises, I found the need to quickly generate a sequence of 1 to n integers. In Ruby, I would do this:

```
numbers = (1..100)
```

Is there something similar in Elixir?

Comment: More generally (for whatever it's worth) this is called a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a very similar feature in Elixir:

```
iex(2)> numbers = 1..10
1..10
iex(3)> Enum.to_list(numbers)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
iex(4)> Enum.map(numbers, fn x -> x * x end)
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

For documentation see [Range](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Range.html)

Comment: Is `Enum.to_list` required to work with that sequence as a list?

Comment: nvm your link to Range has it all :)

Comment: No, the sequence is enumerable (as can be seen from the fact that `Enum.to_list` works for it) so you can use any `Stream` or `Enum` functions on it.

Comment: `Enum.to_list 51..99` gives me `'3456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abc'` does anyone know how I can get `[51, 52, ...]` instead?

Comment: `'3456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_abc'` and `[51, 52, .., 99]` are the same thing in elixir. It's just that `inspect` interprets the list as a charlist, because the items are in printable range. Compare with `Enum.to_list(151..199)`

Comment: Remember when you try to print out the results of a list of integers, you must use the `charlists: :as_lists` option, e.g. `IO.inpsect([51, 52, 53], charlists: :as_lists)` 
This is perhaps THE weirdest historical behavior in Elixir/Erlang, where strings were at one point stored as a list of code points (i.e. integers representing characters) without encodings.